# JSONp requests with tornado

Tags: python, jsonp, tornado, python-2.6

I am wondering how best to handle JSONp objects using tornado in python, 
is it best to do this:

```
class BaseRequest(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
      def prepare(self):
          self.result = {"success": True};
      def finish(self, chunk=None):
          self.write(self.result);
          tornado.web.RequestHandler.finish(self, chunk);
```

This seems like a bad idea because you'd think you could do it in `on_finish()`, right?

So, should I do it like above or should I `write()` in each of my handlers?

Comment: Could do what in on_finish? What does this have to do with JSONp?

Comment: Call self.write() in `on_finish`, you can't do this because the steam has already been closed. Because all my requests will be jsonp results (even though it doesn't look like it, I didn't wrap it in a function that would imply that) it's kinda frustrating to type out the variable containing the result and then the writing the result at the end 10+ times.

Comment: Do it that way if you want, but if it only saves one line, it doesn't seem worth it to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should override the default `write` method and do something like this (untested):

```
class YourHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    ...
    def write(self, stuff):
        super(YourHandler, self).write('callback(' + json.dumps(stuff) + ')')
        self.set_header('Content-Type', 'application/javascript')
```

where `stuff` is a dictionary and `callback` is the jsonp callback name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late on the game here.  The RequestHandler.write function simply creates more chunks onto a write buffer that is later flushed out as a string.

```
class YourHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    ...
    def get(self, stuff):
        self.write("callbackname(")
        self.write(stuff)
        self.write(")")
```